Golang API in Docker Swarm Unable to Retrieve 'users.rpc' Key from etcd, but Key Exists When Queried Directly with etcdctl
I need to deploy a Docker Swarm application stack using the go-zero framework. The architecture consists of a RESTful API service as the entry point for requests. The API then requests the RPC service to implement business logic. The API queries the corresponding RPC service's endpoint through ETCD. My service definition is as follows:
version: '3.8'

services:
  g_api:
    image: <Host IP>:5000/g-api:1.0.5
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - g_etcd
      - g_authrpc
      - g_commentrpc
      - g_userrpc
      - g_msgrpc
      - g_postrpc
    networks:
      - gnet
  g_authrpc:
    image: <Host IP>:5000/g-authrpc:1.0.5
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - g_etcd
    networks:
      - gnet
  g_userrpc:
    image: <Host IP>:5000/g-userrpc:1.0.5
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    command: "./main"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - g_etcd
    networks:
      - gnet
  g_msgrpc:
    image: <Host IP>:5000/g-msgrpc:1.0.5
    ports:
      - "8086:8086"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - g_etcd
    networks:
      - gnet
  g_postrpc:
    image: <Host IP>:5000/g-postrpc:1.0.5
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - g_etcd
    networks:
      - gnet
  g_commentrpc:
    image: <Host IP>:5000/g-commentrpc:1.0.5
    ports:
      - "8152:8152"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - g_etcd
    networks:
      - gnet
  g_etcd:
    image: <Host IP>:5000/etcd:3.5
    ports:
      - "2379:2379"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Shanghai
      - ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION=yes
      - ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://g_etcd:2379
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - gnet
networks:
  gnet:
    driver: overlay

The <Host IP> is the IP of the cloud server.
When I start this Swarm cluster on the Swarm manager server, all other services are in a healthy state, but the API service keeps reporting errors and exiting.

By checking the logs of the g_api service, I found that it keeps reporting errors and exiting, then restarting in a loop. The error message is as follows:
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | 2024/07/01 03:05:57 rpc dial: etcd://141.2.18.177:2379/gauth.rpc, error: context deadline exceeded, make sure rpc service "gauth.rpc" is already started
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | 
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | goroutine 1 [running]:
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | runtime/debug.Stack()
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    |   C:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x5e
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | github.com/zeromicro/go-zero/core/logx.Must({0x20288e0?, 0xc00038a480?})
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    |   C:/Users/vipda/go/pkg/mod/github.com/zeromicro/go-zero@v1.6.0/core/logx/logs.go:225 +0x4b
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | github.com/zeromicro/go-zero/zrpc.MustNewClient({{{0xc000403220, 0x1, 0x1}, {0xc000406810, 0x9}, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, ...}, ...}, ...)
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    |   C:/Users/vipda/go/pkg/mod/github.com/zeromicro/go-zero@v1.6.0/zrpc/client.go:45 +0x65
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | globalfun/app/api/internal/svc.NewServiceContext({{{{0xc000406846, 0x3}, {{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, 0x0, 0x0, ...}, ...}, ...}, ...})
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    |   C:/Users/person/projects/realworld/globalfun-go/globalfun/app/api/internal/svc/servicecontext.go:36 +0xc9
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | main.main()
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    |   C:/Users/person/projects/realworld/globalfun-go/globalfun/app/api/app.go:25 +0x137
global_g_api.1.yv6gvbm93sq7@b3saglvue9qgqseg    | {"@timestamp":"2024-07-01T03:05:57.451Z","content":"rpc dial: etcd://141.2.18.177:2379/gauth.rpc, error: context deadline exceeded, make sure rpc service \"gauth.rpc\" is already started\n\ngoroutine 1 [running]:\nruntime/debug.Stack()\n\tC:/Program Files/Go/src/runtime/debug/stack.go:24 +0x5e\ngithub.com/zeromicro/go-zero/core/logx.Must({0x20288e0?, 0xc00038a480?})\n\tC:/Users/vipda/go/pkg/mod/github.com/zeromicro/go-zero@v1.6.0/core/logx/logs.go:225 +0x4b\ngithub.com/zeromicro/go-zero/zrpc.MustNewClient({{{0xc000403220, 0x1, 0x1}, {0xc000406810, 0x9}, 0x0, {0x0, 0x0}, {0x0, 0x0}, ...}, ...}, ...)\n\tC:/Users/vipda/go/pkg/mod/github.com/zeromicro/go-zero@v1.6.0/zrpc/client.go:45 +0x65\nglobalfun/app/api/internal/svc.NewServiceContext({{{{0xc000406846, 0x3}, {{...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, {...}, 0x0, 0x0, ...}, ...}, ...}, ...})\n\tC:/Users/person/projects/realworld/globalfun-go/globalfun/app/api/internal/svc/servicecontext.go:36 +0xc9\nmain.main()\n\tC:/Users/person/projects/realworld/globalfun-go/globalfun/app/api/app.go:25 +0x137\n","level":"fatal"}

The error message seems to indicate that it cannot find the key gauth.rpc, which I believe was registered with ETCD when the RPC service started.
Therefore, I used etcdctl to get all the keys and retrieved the following content:
commentrpc.rpc/7587879719612179989
10.0.7.12:8152
commentrpc.rpc/7587879719612180006
10.0.7.13:8152
gauth.rpc/7587879719612179977
10.0.7.20:8080
gauth.rpc/7587879719612179981
10.0.7.21:8080
msg.rpc/7587879719612179993
10.0.7.7:8086
msg.rpc/7587879719612179997
10.0.7.6:8086
posts.rpc/7587879719612179973
10.0.7.9:8082
posts.rpc/7587879719612179985
10.0.7.10:8082
users.rpc/7587879719612180001
10.0.7.4:8081
users.rpc/7587879719612180011
10.0.0.3:8081

Obviously, gauth.rpc has already been registered with ETCD, but the API cannot retrieve it. I have been troubleshooting this issue for a few days but still have no clue. I hope to get some help. Thank you, everyone.

I'm unfamiliar with go-zero and only have a basic understanding of Docker Swarm. The error message suggests that the clients are unable to access etcd but it is on a public IP address (141.2.18.177). I would have expected this to be your g_etcd service which should be addressed through a private IP address (10.0.0.0/8) in the Swarm network. When you use etcdctl are you using 141.2.18.177 too? The etcd queries (e.g. gauth.rpc) are resolving to private IP addresses (e.g. 10.0.7.20).

The situation is that I used etcdctl to connect using the public IP and the exposed port of the etcd container. Then, inside the API service container, I tried connecting using  as well as , but both resulted in the aforementioned error. The etcdctl connection command is as follows:
ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=http://141.2.18.177:2379 get "" --prefix

Also, in the API configuration, when I use the service name as the host, it should theoretically resolve to the internal container address, but it still reports an error:
rpc dial: etcd://g_etcd:2379/gauth.rpc, error: context deadline exceeded, make sure rpc service \"gauth.rpc\" is already    So, whether I use the public IP or the service name within the API service container code, I cannot connect to the etcd service.

And my API container code for configuration like below:
Host: 0.0.0.0
Port: 8888

UserRpc:
  Etcd:
    Hosts:
      - g_etcd:2379
    Key: users.rpc

GauthRpc:
  Etcd:
    Hosts:
      - g_etcd:2379
    Key: gauth.rpc


Additionally, 141.2.18.177 is a modified public IP for security reasons. You can consider it as the public IP of a cloud server.

There is no healtcheck configured for g_api - why is/was it failing?

I have resolved the issue. Please forgive my oversight. When configuring the service name in the code's configuration file, I omitted the Docker stack prefix and directly wrote the service name from the YAML file. Now, after adding the Docker stack service prefix, it is working correctly.

